# PHP mailer error

Tags: php, phpmailer

I tried to use php mailer but errors as follows.

```
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:
SMTP -> ERROR: EHLO not accepted from server:
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:
SMTP -> ERROR: HELO not accepted from server:
SMTP -> ERROR: AUTH not accepted from server:
SMTP -> NOTICE: EOF caught while checking if connectedSMTP Error: Could not authenticate. Message could not be sent.

Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
```

and my code

```
 <?php
        require("class.phpmailer.php")
        $mail = new PHPMailer();        
        $mail->IsSMTP();                                    
        $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";  
        $mail->Port = 465;        
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;     

        $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;  
        $mail->Username = "admin@xxxxxxxxxxxx.in";  
        $mail->Password = "xxxxxxxx";   
        $mail->From = "admin@xxxxxxxxxxxx.in";
        $mail->FromName = "Mailer";
        $mail->AddAddress("xxxx@yahoo.co.in", "mine");               
        $mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 
        $mail->IsHTML(true);                                  

        $mail->Subject = "Here is the subject"  
        $mail->Body    = "This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>";
        $mail->AltBody = "This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients";


        if(!$mail->Send())  {
           echo "Message could not be sent. <p>";
           echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
           exit;
        }
        echo "Message has been sent";

        ?>
```

Comment: you need a secure connection, don't you?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Some servers (especially shared hosting) will block you from using SSL with SMTP, I had the same problem once.

Either change host if you can, try using the default PHP mail() function or send through another mail server that does not require SSL e.g. port 25 not 465.

Something like [AuthSMTP](http://www.authsmtp.com/) would be your best bet for an alternate mail server.

Comment: I tried using PHp mail function but that too the mail was not being send.

Answer (score 21):

I was getting this due to wrong port for SSL.

SSL = 465
TLS = 587

See:
http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=13287

Comment: This answer...  this is the one that finally worked for me after much troubleshooting.   Thank you sir.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problems, it seems that we have
to set the SMPTSecure value.
First I changed the port from 465 to 587 and added:
$mail->SMTPSecure   = "tls";
and it worked :)

Answer (score 5):

If you are working in your localhost just go to the **PHP Extention** and enable or check the **php_openssl**
it will be able to access the SSL ports.

Answer (score 3):

try this code

```
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

    //Create a new PHPMailer instance
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    //Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
    $mail->IsSMTP(); 
    //Enable SMTP debugging
    // 0 = off (for production use)
    // 1 = client messages
    // 2 = client and server messages
    //$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;

    //Ask for HTML-friendly debug output
    //$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';

    //Set the hostname of the mail server
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';

    //Set the SMTP port number - 587 for authenticated TLS, a.k.a. RFC4409 SMTP submission
    $mail->Port = 465;

    //Set the encryption system to use - ssl (deprecated) or tls
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';

    //Whether to use SMTP authentication
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;

    //Username to use for SMTP authentication - use full email address for gmail
    $mail->Username = "admin@gmail.com";

    //Password to use for SMTP authentication
    $mail->Password = "admin123";

    $mail->setFrom('admin3@gmail.com', 'development');  //add sender email address.

    $mail->addAddress('admins@gmail.com', "development");  //Set who the message is to be sent to.
    //Set the subject line
    $mail->Subject = $response->subject;

    //Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
    //convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
    $mail->Body     = 'Name: '.$data['name'].'<br />Location: '.$data['location'].'<br />Email: '.$data['email'].'<br />Phone:'.$data['phone'].'<br />ailment: '.$data['ailment'].'<br />symptoms: '.$data['symptoms'];

    //Replace the plain text body with one created manually
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';

    //Attach an image file
    //$mail->addAttachment('images/phpmailer_mini.gif');
    //$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    //send the message, check for errors
    if (!$mail->send()) {
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo "Message sent!";
    }
```

Comment: $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; made the difference for me, thanks!

Comment: I am not the original poster, it just helped me.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue, Change port No in opencart mail setting to  587 and works fine

Answer (score 2):

May be because of fire wall?

> If you can't sign in to Google Talk,
>   or you're receiving an error that
>   says, Could not authenticate to
>   server, check if you have personal
>   firewall software installed, or if
>   your computer is behind a proxy server
>   that requires a username and password.

http://www.google.com/support/talk/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=30998

Comment: talk ain't mail, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

I use the same script for several clients and only run into this problem when deploying to Amazon EC2 cloud providers (such as Openshift).

These are tried and tested settings in phpmailer:
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";                 // sets the prefix to the servier
    $mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
    $mail->Port       = 587;

'but' Google blocks these services as an 'anti-spam' / political maneuver, and this has caught me out because it works locally and on most hosting providers, there is nothing much you can do when they don't accept outbound messages from your hosts DNS / IP. Accept it and move on by looking for another  smtp server to route messages through.

Answer (score 1):

not sure but try `$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com" =>$mail->Host = "smtp.google.com"`