# unable to send mail in php using mailer class

Tags: php, gmail, phpmailer

Today i was doing some mailing stuff in the php, I found that there are two methods for that one is the simple mail function provided by the Php and the second i found on the internet it was about using the PHP mailer class from the site https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer. the problem is that which i run my program than the mail is not being sent. Let's have a look at the code

```
<?php
include 'PHPMailer-master/class.phpmailer.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer();   // create a new object
$mail->IsSMTP();           // enable SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;     // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 
                           //            2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;  // authentication enabled
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail

$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 465; # or 587

$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = "singh6@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "88888*******";

$mail->SetFrom('singh@gmail.com');
$mail->AddAddress('sanu@gmail.com');
$mail->Subject = "Test";
$mail->Body    = "hello";

$sendResult = $mail->Send();

if ($sendResult)
{
     echo "Message has been sent";

}
else
{
     echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

Now when I run this script I get the following error:

```
CLIENT -> SMTP: EHLO localhost 
SMTP -> ERROR: EHLO not accepted from server: 
CLIENT -> SMTP: HELO localhost
```

> Notice: fwrite(): send of 16 bytes failed with errno=10054 An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. in C:\xampp\htdocs\program\mailsending1\mailsending_v1\PHPMailer-master\class.smtp.php on line 1023

```
SMTP -> ERROR: HELO not accepted from server: 
SMTP -> NOTICE: EOF caught while checking if connected
SMTP Connect() failed. 
Mailer Error: SMTP Connect() failed.
```

Comment: tried ' $mail->ErrorInfo ' to get the error?

Comment: Replace `"sending failed"` with `$mail->ErrorInfo` and post the error message.

Comment: posibble duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16048347/send-email-using-gmail-smtp-server-through-php-mailer

Comment: Can you post the error message suggested above?

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method PHPMailer::ErrorInfo() in C:\xampp\htdocs\program\mailsending\mail_notification\mailsend_v2.php on line 28. this the error which i get

Comment: just ErrorInfo, not ErrorInfo()

Comment: Notice: fwrite(): send of 16 bytes failed with errno=10054 An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. in C:\xampp\htdocs\program\mailsending\mail_notification\PHPMailer-master\class.smtp.php on line 1023
sending failedSMTP Connect() failed.

Comment: The error says it all, the remote host closes the connection. Contact the provider of the remote host and ask about the specification of how their system is intended to work with your system. As far as PHPMailer and GMail is concerned, this is likely duplicate material here on stackoverflow.

Comment: You're running on windows. Are you sure that `$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';` is supported by your system? How did you verfiy?

Comment: Try `$mail->SMTPSecure = 'SSL'; $mail->Host = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';` and see if it works. Also verify ports: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/13287?hl=en - TLS requires 587, SSL requires 465 - You're using the wrong port for TLS.

Comment: Also mind two-step verification: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP mailer error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227702/php-mailer-error)

Comment: $mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'SSL'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
$mail->Host = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 465; // or 587 this was my formatted code

Comment: now the error is: SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? (1546610735)SMTP Connect() failed. Mailer Error: SMTP Connect() failed.

Comment: try uncommenting the line **extension=php_openssl.dll** in your php.ini

Comment: You might be using it in local machine

Answer (score 0):

Change the SMTP port to 465. It should work

Comment: For what this line is for? Try removing this line. $mail->Mailer="smtp"; add a text body also. $mail->Body  = 'Test';

Comment: Check whether your firewall is not blocking your outgoing connection. port 465

Answer (score 0):

first try this to find errors

```
if ($mail->Send()) 
{
echo "mail send sucessfully";
}
else 
{
echo "sending failed";
echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
exit;
}
```

put body in your mail

```
$mail->Body="<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en-us'>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
</div>
</body>
</html>";
```

Comment: Notice: fwrite(): send of 16 bytes failed with errno=10054 An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. in C:\xampp\htdocs\program\mailsending\mail_notification\PHPMailer-master\class.smtp.php on line 1023
sending failedSMTP Connect() failed.

Comment: try this
$mail->Host = 'smtpout.secureserver.net';
$mail->Port = '80';

Comment: i added the body and used the host and the port u provided but i get the error:SMTP Connect() failed.

Comment: do this
$mail->SMTPSecure = '';

Comment: check your username and password

Comment: @user1334573 : use  $mail->SMTPDebug  = 1; to debug

Comment: Notice: fwrite(): send of 16 bytes failed with errno=10054 An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. in C:\xampp\htdocs\program\mailsending\mail_notification\PHPMailer-master\class.smtp.php on line 1023.   this the error now
sending failedSMTP Connect() failed