# SMTP error with PHPMailer EHLO not supported

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

I have this code, which I want to use to send mails to my customers, PARAMETERS CENSORED (`***`):

```
include 'phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
$mail->Host = "smtp.email.it";
$mail->Port = 25; // or 587 465
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Username = "***";
$mail->Password = "***";
$mail->SetFrom('***');
$mail->Subject = "Test";
$mail->Body = "hello";
$mail->AddAddress('***');
 if(!$mail->Send())
    {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
    else
    {
    echo "Message has been sent";
    }
```

It connects but gives errors:

```
2013-10-13 09:13:25 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO *SITE_CENSORED*
2013-10-13 09:13:25 SMTP ERROR: EHLO command failed: Method EHLO is not supported.
2013-10-13 09:13:25 SMTP NOTICE: EOF caught while checking if connected
SMTP connect() failed.
Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.
```

Comment: Looks like badly configures SMTP server, phpmailer should try `HELO` if `EHLO` failed, but server closes connection after unrecognized command. You can try [changing order of these commands](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/class.smtp.php#L592)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227702/php-mailer-error

Comment: @dev-null-dweller Now it says `Method HELO is not supported`...

Comment: @AnthonySterling I can use it even without SSL or TLS, is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 4):

Changing your port to `587` should work:

```
$mail->Port = 587; // or 587 465
```

I tried to telnet:

```
telnet smtp.email.it 25 //not working

telnet smtp.email.it 465 //not working

telnet smtp.email.it 587 //works
```

Comment: strange, when I typed in commands via telnet, both HELO and EHLO worked. Are you using the latest version of PHPMailer?