# smtp is not working in php - Godaddy hosting service

Tags: php, smtp

I am trying to use php-mailer-class but getting different issue.

Please take a look on my code.

```
include ("class.phpmailer.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer();  // create a new object
$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug =1;  // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
//$mail->SMTPAuth = true;  // authentication enabled

$mail->Host = 'relay-hosting.secureserver.net';
$mail->Port = 25;
$mail->Username = "admin@****.in"; 
$mail->Password = "******";          
$mail->SetFrom('*****0014@gmail.com', 'User name');
$mail->Subject = 'mailing';
$mail->Body = "<b>Hi, your e- mail has been received.</b>";
$mail->AddAddress("*****0014@gmail.com");
if(!$mail->Send()) {
   $error = 'Mail error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo;
   return false;
} else {
$error = 'Message sent!';
   return true;
}
```

errors-:

```
SMTP -> ERROR: EHLO not accepted from server: 
SMTP -> ERROR: HELO not accepted from server: 
SMTP -> NOTICE: EOF caught while checking if connectedThe following From address failed: *****0014@gmail.com
```

**This code is working well if I am using Gamil settings** Not working with godaddy SMTP settings.

Comment: smtp has nothing to do with php its server side not from php side

Comment: Probably the relay forbids unencrypted smtp connections on port 25?

Comment: You have not included class.smtp of phpmailer @vipul Sharma

Comment: I am using godaddy is well.! Godaddy doesn’t allow out SMTP servers, like gmail, or others. they force users to use their own servers, I used SMTP with godaddy it was to slow, and mails were coming after 3-5 minutes or was never getting emails sometimes, I switched to mail() function still slow but much better than using godaddy SMTP servers. I recommend you to use mail() function instead. Side note : godaddy is a horrible hosting provider service.

Comment: I have been facing the same problem. I have tried using the mail() function, emails are delivered, but sent emails are not saved. I am using gmail.

Answer (score 1):

I checked your code, and expecting few reasons for the error.

1. Port no/host declaration wrong
2. SMTP class not available.

if the above both are solved, please modify the code by adding the extra line as follows.

```
$mail->Host = 'relay-hosting.secureserver.net';
$mail->Port = 25;
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
```

This found working well in my server.

From [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227702/php-mailer-error) question, it describes the server blocking of SSL SMTP connection in shared hosting. So make the mailer to use TLS, to do so, change port no and SMTP mode.

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
$mail->Port = 587;
```

And specifically you told that you are using godaddy hosting, as per [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21841834/phpmailer-godaddy-server-smtp-connection-refused) question, change your host configuration to

```
$mail->Host = localhost;
```

Comment: SMTP -> NOTICE: EOF caught while checking if connectedSMTP Error: Could not authenticate.  getting this error

Comment: SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection refused (111)
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.

Comment: shared hosting on Godaddy . But i dont know how to check SMTP ACCESS

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90104/discussion-between-vipul-sharma-and-subin-thomas).

Answer (score 1):

Too late but helpful for other.

GoDaddy blocks all outgoing SMTP connections except for their own.

Call GoDaddy and ask them to add SMTP relay (eg gmail smtp.gmail.com) on server.

Answer (score 0):

First include `include("PHPMailerAutoload.php");` and PHPmailerAutoload.php will load a class that you need, in your case class.smtp.php.

```
include("PHPMailerAutoload.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();  // create a new object
$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug =1;  // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only

$mail->SMTPAuth = true;  // authentication enabled
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl"; // sets the prefix to the servier
$mail->Host = "box###.bluehost.com"; // sets the SMTP server
$mail->Port = 465; // set the SMTP port

$mail->Username = "admin@****.in"; 
$mail->Password = "******";          
$mail->SetFrom('admin@****.in', 'Sender name');
$mail->Subject = 'mailing';
$mail->Body = "<b>Hi, your e- mail has been received.</b>";
$mail->AddAddress("*****0014@gmail.com", "User name");
if(!$mail->Send()) {
   $error = 'Mail error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo;
   return false;
} else {
$error = 'Message sent!';
   return true;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain the changes?? @Mladen

Comment: @SubinThomas SetForm must be same value as username because you canot send email from admin@****.in using SMTP as another person/email.

Comment: You can set anything in setfrom. even can be CEO@google.com

Comment: @vipulsharma does you hosting support smtp? Do u use shared hosting or VPS?

Comment: @vipulsharma i just edit code for sharedhosting on bluehost.

Comment: @vipulsharma HOST "box###.bluehost.com" u can find when u login to ur bluehost acc then go to Email Accounts on select ur email adress and click on more button and then on Cofigure Email Client. When new page load u can find ur SMTP, PORT and all other stuff u need.

The same procedure is forl all shared hosting who use cpanel

Answer (score 0):

@vipulsharma,Its simple, you don't need to mentions host url directly to "relay-hosting.secureserver.net" because you are using the shared hosting so you have to point your host destination to your localhost folder only. For shared hosting, GoDaddy already configured the host setting internally.   do change in the following changes in your code.

```
$mail->Host= 'localhost';
$mail->ssl=false;
$mail->authentication=false;
$mail->Port=25;
```